# When do django AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES run with respect to Middleware

Tags: django, django-middleware

I see there is a `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` but reading the documentation I don't think it determines when auth is actually auth is run. Does auth happen before or after middleware? Can that ordering be changed?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to ask.

Comment: django has a list of middleware and a list of authentication_classes defined in its settings. When receiving a request, all of these are run, but it's not clear which runs first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication process and AuthenticationMiddleware unfortunately have little to do with each other. Authentication as a process is the practice of verifying credentials. In order to not have to do this for each request, one can create a "login session", which associates the browser with an authentication process that happened in the past. For the end user this is transparent as a "login process". This results in a "logged in user" and AuthenticationMiddleware puts this logged in user on the request object as `request.user` or if no login process has occurred, then the `AnonymousUser`.

In Django, authentication is done by whatever calls `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` and the login process by `django.contrib.auth.login`. In a vanilla installation this is done by `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`, which isn't hooked up to any url, except the admin login.

Authentication backends are not middleware. They are sources of truth for authentication data that is queried by the `authenticate` function. It's list is executed in order defined by the settings and the first one that returns `True` wins.

I think in the past the intention was for the authentication middleware to do more, but as it stands, a better name would be `CurrentUserMiddleware`.

### No fixed place

You seem to think there is one spot where authentication backends are called on each request. This isn't the case, but depending on the authentication method, it can be. For example, Django Rest Framework's token authentication sends a token header on each request, which is authenticated each time in the view.

In theory, one can create a middleware that authenticates and sets the authenticated user each time, especially with token based auth, as they send credentials with each request. It's just unpractical, because it becomes harder and less explicit to exclude views from the process.

Comment: from this answer I'm still not quite clear on whether django auth backends will run before or after middleware

Comment: "In a vanilla installation this is done by django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView, which isn't hooked up to any url, except the admin login.", so in a default install, in a view that is only hooked up to the admin. Views run after middleware on the request ingress and before Middleware on the response egress. If that's not clear, you're looking for an answer you're not asking the right question for.

Comment: In my case I have a token-based authentication class where a header is checked each request, but even with the default LoginView I assume there is a cookie or session id that is checked on each request? Basically if I make a request, there is some code that raises a 401 if the correct auth data is not given - does that occur before or after middleware?

Comment: Session is done in Middleware. Token auth, as I explained several times in the view, which comes (for simplicity's sake) after the middleware. Session auth doesn't raise 401.